# Draw element along a round rect path Android

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas

I am building a watch face and I want to draw ticks along a rounded rectangle path but I don't know where I should start from.

Is there a method that allows to create a shape (round rect in this scenario) and then get the points of it every x pixels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started.

```
    //Path for a rounded rectangle.
    path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(rx, 0);
    path.lineTo(width - rx, 0);
    path.quadTo(width, 0, width,ry);
    path.lineTo(width, height-ry);
    path.quadTo(width, height, width-rx,height);
    path.lineTo(rx, height);
    path.quadTo(0,height, 0, height-ry);
    path.lineTo(0,ry);
    path.quadTo(0, 0, rx, 0);
    //valid APIs less than 21.

    float centerX = (x+width)/2;
    float centerY = (y+height)/2;
    //get center point

    int number_of_ticks = 60;
    int amount_towards_center = 10;

    ticks =  new Path();
    PathMeasure pathMeasure = new PathMeasure(path, false);
    float fSegmentLen = pathMeasure.getLength() / number_of_ticks;
    float afP[] = {0f, 0f};

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_ticks; i++) {
        pathMeasure.getPosTan(fSegmentLen * i, afP, null);
        ticks.moveTo(afP[0], afP[1]);
        float dX = (centerX-afP[0]) / amount_towards_center;
        float dY = (centerY-afP[1]) / amount_towards_center;
        ticks.lineTo(afP[0]+dX, afP[1]+dY);
    }
```

In fact, if you don't want to get fancy it might get you finished too.

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
    canvas.drawPath(ticks,paint);
    canvas.drawPath(path,paint);
}
```

And paint sans fill:

```
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
```